# visual studio code tokenization skipped for long lines

Tags: editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT5K4.png)

Hello, I downloaded HTML file and opened it in visual studio code, then I have found the code like this on the picture with no any spaces. and it says tokenization skipped for long lines.

please, what is this problem and how can I solve it in order to see the code correctly arranged and with spaces?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the file may have been [minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and all unnecessary white space and new line characters removed. You could try to unminify it with an online tool like [this](https://unminify.com/) or [this](https://www.unminify2.com/). It also might help to include the code here in your question so that people can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> Open Settings (UI)

Here is where you will find the file that contains the following default setting:

```
editor.maxTokenizationLineLength": 20000
```